Can I get one directory above __DIR__ in a constant expression?
What I would like to do is this:
const LEVEL_UP = dirname(__DIR__).'/templates/';

But dirname is a runtime function and cannot be used in a constant expression.
Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations

Is there any constant expression way to truncate one level off of __DIR__?

if you don't need absolute paths you could use  __DIR__.'/../templates'

You could also evaluate the expression and then have the file overwrite itself.
